# How to map to multiple elements with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, lambda, closures, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like this:

```
class MultiDataPoint {
  private DateTime timestamp;
  private Map<String, Number> keyToData;
}
```

and i want to produce , for each MultiDataPoint

```
class DataSet {
        public String key;    
        List<DataPoint> dataPoints;
}

class DataPoint{
  DateTime timeStamp;
  Number data;
}
```

of course a 'key' can be the same across multiple MultiDataPoints.

So given a `List<MultiDataPoint>`, how do I use Java 8 streams to convert to `List<DataSet>`?

This is how I am currently doing the conversion without streams:

```
Collection<DataSet> convertMultiDataPointToDataSet(List<MultiDataPoint> multiDataPoints)
{

    Map<String, DataSet> setMap = new HashMap<>();

    multiDataPoints.forEach(pt -> {
        Map<String, Number> data = pt.getData();
        data.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            String seriesKey = e.getKey();
            DataSet dataSet = setMap.get(seriesKey);
            if (dataSet == null)
            {
                dataSet = new DataSet(seriesKey);
                setMap.put(seriesKey, dataSet);
            }
            dataSet.dataPoints.add(new DataPoint(pt.getTimestamp(), e.getValue()));
        });
    });

    return setMap.values();
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's an interesting question, because it shows that there are a lot of different approaches to achieve the same result. Below I show three different implementations.

---

**Default methods in Collection Framework:** Java 8 added some methods to the collections classes, that are not directly related to the *Stream API*. Using these methods, you can significantly simplify the implementation of the non-stream implementation:

```
Collection<DataSet> convert(List<MultiDataPoint> multiDataPoints) {
    Map<String, DataSet> result = new HashMap<>();
    multiDataPoints.forEach(pt ->
        pt.keyToData.forEach((key, value) ->
            result.computeIfAbsent(
                key, k -> new DataSet(k, new ArrayList<>()))
            .dataPoints.add(new DataPoint(pt.timestamp, value))));
    return result.values();
}
```

---

**Stream API with flatten and intermediate data structure:** The following implementation is almost identical to the solution provided by Stuart Marks. In contrast to his solution, the following implementation uses an *anonymous inner class* as intermediate data structure.

```
Collection<DataSet> convert(List<MultiDataPoint> multiDataPoints) {
    return multiDataPoints.stream()
        .flatMap(mdp -> mdp.keyToData.entrySet().stream().map(e ->
            new Object() {
                String key = e.getKey();
                DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(mdp.timestamp, e.getValue());
            }))
        .collect(
            collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(t -> t.key, mapping(t -> t.dataPoint, toList())),
                m -> m.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new DataSet(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(toList())));
}
```

---

**Stream API with map merging:** Instead of flattening the original data structures, you can also create a *Map* for each *MultiDataPoint*, and then merge all maps into a single map with a reduce operation. The code is a bit simpler than the above solution:

```
Collection<DataSet> convert(List<MultiDataPoint> multiDataPoints) {
    return multiDataPoints.stream()
        .map(mdp -> mdp.keyToData.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> asList(new DataPoint(mdp.timestamp, e.getValue())))))
        .reduce(new HashMap<>(), mapMerger())
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new DataSet(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

You can find an implementation of the *map merger* within the *Collectors* class. Unfortunately, it is a bit tricky to access it from the outside. Following is an alternative implementation of the *map merger*:

```
<K, V> BinaryOperator<Map<K, List<V>>> mapMerger() {
    return (lhs, rhs) -> {
        Map<K, List<V>> result = new HashMap<>();
        lhs.forEach((key, value) -> result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(value));
        rhs.forEach((key, value) -> result.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(value));
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: @pdeva: I agree. In particular, as long as developers are not used to functional programming, I think you should avoid overusing the Stream API.

Comment: Nice set of alternatives.

Comment: I had no idea that you could type-safely refer to fields of an anonymous class later on in a stream; very nice!

Answer (score 14):

To do this, I had to come up with an intermediate data structure:

```
class KeyDataPoint {
    String key;
    DateTime timestamp;
    Number data;
    // obvious constructor and getters
}
```

With this in place, the approach is to "flatten" each MultiDataPoint into a list of (timestamp, key, data) triples and stream together all such triples from the list of MultiDataPoint.

Then, we apply a `groupingBy` operation on the string key in order to gather the data for each key together. Note that a simple `groupingBy` would result in a map from each string key to a list of the corresponding KeyDataPoint triples. We don't want the triples; we want DataPoint instances, which are (timestamp, data) pairs. To do this we apply a "downstream" collector of the `groupingBy` which is a `mapping` operation that constructs a new DataPoint by getting the right values from the KeyDataPoint triple. The downstream collector of the `mapping` operation is simply `toList` which collects the DataPoint objects of the same group into a list.

Now we have a `Map<String, List<DataPoint>>` and we want to convert it to a collection of DataSet objects. We simply stream out the map entries and construct DataSet objects, collect them into a list, and return it.

The code ends up looking like this:

```
Collection<DataSet> convertMultiDataPointToDataSet(List<MultiDataPoint> multiDataPoints) {
    return multiDataPoints.stream()
        .flatMap(mdp -> mdp.getData().entrySet().stream()
                           .map(e -> new KeyDataPoint(e.getKey(), mdp.getTimestamp(), e.getValue())))
        .collect(groupingBy(KeyDataPoint::getKey,
                    mapping(kdp -> new DataPoint(kdp.getTimestamp(), kdp.getData()), toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new DataSet(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(toList());
}
```

I took some liberties with constructors and getters, but I think they should be obvious.

Comment: i have removed the 'Series' constructor from my code now to align with the answer

Comment: is it just me or the stream version looks more complicated and requires another data structure than the imperative version..

Comment: There might be a way to remove the intermediate data structure. It will require more thought. Whether the streams version is more complicated is a matter of taste, I think. If you know what `groupingBy` does, it makes perfect sense, but I had to stare at the original code for a while to realize that it was essentially doing a grouping operation.